# SQL Server: DISTINCT with joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to print total number of orders of each state year-wise. But this is printing multiple states and not distinct.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    customer_state, 
    COUNT(*), 
    YEAR(order_purchase_timestamp) AS year 
FROM
    olist_orders_dataset 
JOIN 
    olist_customers_dataset ON olist_orders_dataset.customer_id = olist_customers_dataset.customer_id
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(order_purchase_timestamp), customer_state
```

I am getting this output:

| State | Year | Num_orders |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AC | 2020 | 123 |
| AC | 2020 | 1234 |
| AC | 2019 | 234 |

Here is the Required Output:

| State | Year | Num_orders |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AC | 2020 | 19995 |
| CA | 2020 | 188891 |
| AL | 2019 | 11999 |

Comment: A `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY` is always a sign of a flaw in your query. A `GROUP BY` already causes your data to be returned in *distinct* sets, so if you are getting duplicates, it likely means your `GROUP BY` is wrong. Otherwise the `DISTINCT` is redundant and unneeded overhead.

Comment: Why you would *not* expect multiple states? You'll get 1 row per year and state combination; why would you only expect 1 state to be displayed? If you want to filter to a specific state you need to use a `WHERE`.

Comment: I need to display Total yearly orders of each state, thus the distinct feature. i did as per you said, removed distinct and used group by, but its still giving the same result

Comment: Of course it will give the same result. As I stated the `DISTINCT` is either redundant or your `GROUP BY` is wrong; it is clearly the former. The `DISTINCT` should *not* be there; there should *never* be a `DISTINCT` in the same scope as a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You need to add more information about why you think your result is not correct. No one can read your mind or see your screen or query your data. You know that you **intentionally** group by year and state but you complain about "printing multiple states". Do you see why people are confused?

Comment: Take the time to supply us with sample data, in a **consumable** format *not an image*, and expected results here. You have not sufficiently explained the problem.

Comment: I have update the question to show more clarity

Comment: You haven't given any sample data here, @AdrianJaraine . Where did those rows for other states come from if they weren't in your original data? That ***can't*** happen with that query; it is **literally** impossible.

Comment: Your description in the first paragraph of what you want is self-contradictory. You say you want the "number of orders of each state" - which necessarily means you want to see data from multiple states - but then in the very next sentence you complain about seeing data from multiple states.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, I don't think it should be necessary to point out that your "output" doesn't match your query. Different column order and names. And somehow 2 rows for CA (123 and 1234) become 1 row (19995)? Math isn't that difficult. Simple oversights of that nature suggest a lack of effort.

Your output suggests that the two values you see as "AC" are not actually the same. Typically this means there is a trailing character that is not displayable (e.g., tab or linefeed). If that is the case, then you must first "fix" your data and then fix the process that is populating your table.

To verify that this is the problem, you can convert the column to `varbinary` to see the hex values stored in it. Example:

```
select customer_state, cast(customer_state as varbinary(20)) as bin_state, count(*) 
from @tbl 
where customer_state like 'AC%'
group by customer_state order by customer_state
;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=23667a628c1b78e6c721be0b8f01e7c4) to demonstrate. If my guess is correct, then there is an important lesson to learn. Stop throwing code into a query to fix a problem without understanding the cause.

And one last note. Aggregation tends to produce rows in some order. That is an artifact of the execution plans. If the order of rows in your resultset matters (and it usually does), the query MUST have an `ORDER BY` clause. That applies to every query - not just those using aggregation.